# Why did Voldemort faint when he "killed" Harry?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

This is a simple question:

Did Voldemort faint because of the blood connection between him and Harry,

> or because of the Horcrux inside Harry?

Those are the 2 things that connect Voldemort to Harry so I am assuming it's one of those reasons.

Comment: We see that when Nagini gets killed he has a moment of pain/weakness what allowed Harry to defeat him. So it would be logical to assume that each time one of his horcruxes gets destroyed it's a heavy blow against him.

Comment: @A.bakker This is a movie only occurance. In the books he has absolutely no idea his Horcuxes are even being targeted until they steal the one at the bank. It doesnt affect him at all when they are destroyed. He is also not affected/doesnt even know when Nagini is destroyed in the book.

Comment: @GamerGypps that's why i posted it as a comment. not a full blown answer.

Comment: @A.bakker That doesnt make it any less wrong. Its a big plot point that he has no idea his horcruxes are even being targeted. So the comment is just incorrect information that doesnt help.

Comment: @GamerGypps it is wrong if we follow the book, likely if we follow the film. We do not currently know which one he is referring to...

Comment: @GamerGypps The actual question is, though, if he faints when killing Harry in the book too. If he doesn't, then the comment is as correct as it can be and the following discussion is entirely moot. If he doesn't, then it's at least partly a correct assumption depending on what the question is asking about.

Comment: @TARS In both the film and the book he has no idea that his horcuxes are being targeted. The instance with Nagini is the only time it has any affect. He also faints or is at least knocked over in the book too so the question is perfectly valid.

Comment: @GamerGypps just because he doesn't know the Horcruxes are being hunted doesn't mean it doesn't effect him. A possible theory is that each time a horcrux gets destroyed he get a punch... the fewer that are left the harder the punch...that would explain why killing Harry Knocked him out and the death of Nagini weakening him tot he point that Harry (who is still not a magical master at this point) is able to kill him.

Comment: The blood connection is most likely the reason because Voldemort never fainted when the other Horcruxes were destroyed.

Comment: @A.bakker Harry was able to kill Voldemort for several reasons. The horcruxes being destroyed just made him mortal again. It doesnt make him any less powerful as a wizard though. Harry was the master of the elder wand which refused to kill its master as noted in several other high profile questions. He also sacrificed himself to ensure Voldemort could not harm anyone ever again. This protection extended to himself as noted in this answer https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19035/why-didnt-harry-feel-the-cruciatus-curse-at-the-end-of-deathly-hallows.

Comment: @A.bakker https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7312/why-didnt-voldemort-collect-the-horcruxes-after-he-was-resurrected This anwser explicitly says that Voldemort could not feel his Horcruxes being destroyed at all.

Comment: @GamerGypps again this is book, and book and film are not the same....and again i did not post an answer but a theory in the comments... also this isn't for extended debates...